# Can I efficiently limit the number of matches find gives me?

Tags: c++, unix, boost, find

I'm applying find to a large directory tree with tens of thousands of files to find all csv files with a certain name as part of an internal user facing application.

> find /path/to/dirs -name filename.ext | head -n 100

This takes a fair amount of time (up to a minute in some cases) and I suspect it would be considerably faster to find just the first 100 matches (or less if there aren't any) and return those. Is this possible with `find` without piping the output to head (which requires finding all matches)? I didn't see any option that caught my eye in the `info` pages. If not (as I suspect), are there any other unix tools that do this already?

Alternatively, how could I modify this code from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C.2B.2B) into such a tool?

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
  path current_dir("."); //
  boost::regex pattern("a.*"); // list all files starting with a
  for (recursive_directory_iterator iter(current_dir), end;
       iter != end;
       ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string();
    if (regex_match(name, pattern))
      std::cout << iter->path() << "\n";
  }
}
```

I must admit I'm not a C++ programmer, but I suspect this code could be modified pretty easily by someone who does into a shell tool that took a `path` argument, a `filename` argument, and a `max` argument and printed full file paths of at most `max` files named `filename` under directory `path`.

While I'm not a C++ programmer, I did write a UNIX tool (in Racket) to do this today. I'll try and post some benchmarks later to compare it with `find`.

Comment: I never used it, but `locate` seems to have some kind of caching. When you stll have problems, think of anther way to organise your files. As  a lost resort (when the csv files seldom change), use something as a `all_csv_files.txt` and fill that up with every new file or using crontab.

Comment: `find` also seems to do some caching. I've noticed the second search is almost instantaneous. But the first one takes a long time. `locate` would be useful if I could focus it on a specific directory location and not the whole system and have my tool fall back on `find` if it found no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q.** "Is this possible with find without piping the output to head (which requires finding all matches)"

that's false. When `head` is satisfied, it ends, closing the pipe. `find` will exit with SIGPIPE (13) so it's  doesn't require finding all matches

Comment: Interesting. If that is so, then I'm curious why it is so slow. Still, I had no idea pipes worked that way. Thanks.

Comment: Warning: on windows there might be suboptimal emulations (though seriously, in the last decade tools have been ported quite well)